# How to assign a customized URL to an enterprise project in project center?

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server, ms-project, project-online, pwa

I've created a project "test project" using desktop MSP connected to SharePoint server. Clicking on "test project" opens it in a page with an URL composed of a  long sequence of characters.

How can I change this URL to something meaningful like:

```
http://server-name:46361/sites/PWA/TestProject
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Settings gear, in **PWA Settings** go to
 **Operational Policies** then  **Connected SharePoint Sites** . Choose the project and click "Create Site"...